# Siri Integration in iOS for Payment transfer

Tags: ios, siri

I  have to integrate Siri in our application for Sending payments to persons. Regarding this I have some questions,

1. I got some sample applications in which person name is captured from contacts present in phone or user generated contacts. So can any one please tell me is it possible to fetch the some list for e.g beneficiary list and from this we can choose the beneficiary and then use it as payee at the time of resolving payee details. And suppose fetching of beneficiary list is not possible then how payment is work?
2. How to capture details of who(Payer) is sending money to other person. For e,g as I have to integrate it in bank application so no data is locally saved. and to fetch the details we need to call an API. So how it will work.
3. While confirmation for authorizing payer we can use Touch ID. So is there any other way for iPhone 4,5 devices which are not supporting touch ID authorization.
4. What is the timeout for siri when we ask for payment request. And what to do to handle the payment processing at app level.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

giving answer to my question so that any one get help from this.

1. At this stage it is not possible to fetch the beneficiary list. We need to fetch the person name from contact itself.
2. We can achieve this using App group sharing.
3. For this we can switch them to our application using NSUserActivity.
4. Timeout is not specified but Siri wait for some time until api is not get any response.